Occasional weird sounds from rear of bike
Usually when not peddling and going fast (road, downhill) this sound happens
It usually stops after peddling (forward or backwards)
Any ideas what might be wrong?
https://1drv.ms/v/s!ApXgO1jaK-JlkcdxVP0GNZr0_loo5w

Be careful, the chain is so slack that is being caught between the rear tyre and the chain stay.
It stops when your pedalling because tension is regained and the chain recovers into it's proper position.
When using the smaller rear cassette sprockets, try a different front gear combination so that your bicycle chain rides on your bigger chain wheel increasing chain tension and hopefully stopping it from dangling between your chain stay and tyre.
If that does not help then check the rear derailleur, you may have to shorten your chain or there is something wrong with the freewheel/freehub where the rear derailleur is not able to keep tension through the whole chain loop.




Also, follow Warren's answer because when not pedalling, something is making your cassette want to spin together with your wheel, which is causing the top side of your chain loop to slacken and your derailleur to max-out the chain tension mechanism.

Your plastic spoke protector is rubbing against the cassette. When you pedal the two are not moving relative to each other and the noise stops.
Squirt some WD-40 between cassette and disk and listen if the noise changes to confirm.
There might be a twig or a leaf stuck in there somewhere.
You can remove the disk as it’s not essential but it does remove the risk of chomping your drive side spokes if the chain derails too far on that side.
Personally I’d avoid removing it and try to fix the rubbing issues, maybe with some subtle zip tie engineering.
